# Freeing an allocated binary tree - C programming

Tags: c, malloc, binary-tree

```
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
};
```

Creating a node to be inserted function:

```
struct node* create_node(int val) {

 // Allocate space for the node, set the fields.
 struct node* temp;
 temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
 temp->data = val;
 temp->left = NULL;
 temp->right = NULL;

 return temp; // Return a pointer to the created node.
}
```

My insert node function:

```
struct node* insert(struct node *root, struct node *element) {

 if (root == NULL)
   return element;
 else {

   // element should be inserted to the right.
   if (element->data > root->data) {

     // There is a right subtree to insert the node.
     if (root->right != NULL)
       root->right = insert(root->right, element);

     // Place the node directly to the right of root.
     else
       root->right = element;
   }

   // element should be inserted to the left.
   else {

     // There is a left subtree to insert the node.
     if (root->left != NULL)
       root->left = insert(root->left, element);

     // Place the node directly to the left of root.
     else
       root->left = element;
   }

   // Return the root pointer of the updated tree.
   return root;
 }
}
```

My main where I am inserting the nodes into the tree:

```
    scanf("%d", &numCases);

    for(i=0; i<numCases;i++){

        scanf("%d", &numNodes);

        for(j=0; j < numNodes; j++){
            scanf("%d", &val);
            temp_node = create_node(val);
            my_root = insert(my_root, temp_node);
        }
// calling the function to free the tree after all nodes have been inserted
postOrderFree(my_root);
```

Now my plan was to use a Post order traverse method to free each node, but when I try to use my Post order function it doesn't seem to work properly. It doesnt free any nodes at all and for every case I give it, it will keep adding nodes to the previous tree, until it inevitably crashes.

This is the Post order traverse function I'm trying to use:

```
void postOrderFree(struct node* root){
    if(root != NULL) {
        postOrderFree(root->left);
        postOrderFree(root->right);
        free(root->data);
    }
}
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated, including style and if there is any redundancies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your postOrderFree() function frees the wrong thing..

It should be

```
 free(root);
```

instead of

```
  free(root->data);
```

After you have freed' the binary tree, you must set your root node back to NULL too, else it will be a dangling pointer.
That is you have to do this:

```
 postOrderFree(my_root);
 my_root = NULL;
```

Comment: void postOrderFree(struct node* root){
    if(root != NULL) {
        postOrderFree(root->left);
        postOrderFree(root->right);
        free(root);
        postOrderFree(root);
        root = NULL;
    }
} Is this correct? This is crashing for me.

Comment: I set the my_root in main to NULL and it ran properly. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Since you allocated memory for the node, not the data, you should not free the node data, but the node itself:

```
void postOrderFree(struct node* root){
    if(root != NULL) {
        postOrderFree( root->left );
        postOrderFree( root->right );
        free( root );
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this aswell, it will crash the program on the first attempt to free the root.

Comment: After the `free( root );` line, you need to add another line. `root = NULL; `.